# hide submit button again after clicking (ng-show - form validation)

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code, which shows the a.btn anchor if both inputs have values and inputURL is a valid URL. Works fine but I want to hide the button again on click, how do I do this, do I reset the form or actually hide the  button on click?

```
  <form name="myForm" class="row inputs">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a Title/Description</label>
            <input name="inputName" type="text" id="urlName" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a URL</label>
            <input type="url" name="inputURL" id="urlLink" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvUrl" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="javascript:" ng-click="saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post" ng-show="myForm.$valid">Post</a>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've done before is create a scope variable in your controller:

```
$scope.formSubmitted = false;
```

Then in your saveToList function set $scope.formSubmitted to true.  From here you have a few options.  If you're "Post" button is an actual button then you could set the disabled attribute.  You could also check if formSubmitted is true inside your saveToList function and if it is true you don't continue.  Or you can change your ng-show to be:

```
ng-show="myForm.$valid && !formSubmitted"
```

Comment: $scope.formSubmitted = false << you do not need this actually)

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - You're right, good point.  I added it because I feel it helps explain what's going on.

Comment: ok that doesn't work, I added ng-show="myForm.$valid && !formSubmitted" and   $scope.formSubmitted = true; in the savetolist function, but now doesn't disappear. @Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

define another `$scope.someToggle` variable, and assign it `true`, then at the `ng-show` of the button add it like `ng-show="myForm.$valid && someToggle"`. then at the end (or in callback) of `saveToList($event)` function, set `$scope.someToggle` to `false`.

also you can put this on both inputs: `ng-change = "someToggle = true"` so whenever they change(after the save button has been clicked) you'd be able to bring it back...

Comment: the `ng-show`'s expression wont happen unless you change it's `model`'s value. so unless you change the inputs' values somewhere in the way (like emptying them inside the function or something like that), this wont happen.
are you sure the `ng-show` is written correctly?

Comment: In the function I empty them   `urlName.value = ''; //urlName is the ID of  
 urlLink.value = ''; //urlName is the ID of  input box - Angular rocks!`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" class row inputs">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a Title/Description</label>
            <input name="inputName" type="text" id="urlName" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter a URL</label>
            <input type="url" name="inputURL" id="urlLink" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="mvUrl" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="javascript:" ng-click="saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post" ng-show="myForm.$valid">Post</a>
      </div>

    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {   

    $scope.saveToList = function() {            
        $scope.mvName = '';
        $scope.mvUrl = '';              
    }

});
```

***Alternative***

**with scope variable without invalidating form**

```
 <a href="javascript:" ng-click="saveToList($event)" class="btn btn-block post" ng-show="myForm.$valid {{logicalExp}} !formSubmitted">Post</a>

app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {   

    $scope.logicalExp = "||";
    $scope.formSubmitted = true;

    $scope.saveToList = function() {            
        $scope.logicalExp = "&&";
          $scope.formSubmitted = true;              
    }
  });
```

the problem with this is, user needs to invalidate the form by himself by removing entered value then hyperlink will be hidden-ed.

Comment: where on this one do I set it to false again=? @Pratap A.K

Comment: When you want to set it to false?

Comment: thing is it sets to true then it's always true.

Comment: One caveat with this solution is you are just invalidating the form.  So if the form submission had an error or for some reason you needed to have the user go back and modify their entries, you have blown them all away so they'd have to re-enter them all.  I prefer to have a scope variable to disable the button.

Comment: Question demands the same.. we have to invalidate form in order to hide hyperlink again. $scope wont fit this requirement .